# Vuetify tooltip prevent "v-if" component to reappear

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a button which should be displayed if a value is bigger than 2, so I wrote a "v-if" condition. Everything works fine, but when I add a tooltip, the button doesn't reappear when the "v-if" conditionis fulfilled.

Here is the example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      val: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-container fluid class="text-center">
        <v-row
          class="flex"
          justify="space-between"
        >
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-btn @click="val++">+</v-btn>
            <v-btn @click="val--">-</v-btn>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12">
            {{ val }}
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" class="mt-2">
            <v-tooltip bottom>
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn color="green" v-if="val > 2" v-on="on">
                  > 2
                </v-btn>
              </template>
              <span>tooltip</span>
            </v-tooltip>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" class="mt-12">
            <v-btn color="blue" v-if="val > 2" v-on="on">
              > 2
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Could anybody give me a clue on what happens here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: open your console F12 and check if some errors appearing. it could be that your vue.js app stops to work properly on an error

Comment: There is no error in my console,you can check here if you want: https://codepen.io/djcaesar9114/pen/dyYLXOO?editors=1011

Comment: I see this error: ""[Vue warn]: Property or method 'on' is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the `v-if` directive on the `v-tooltip` element instead of the button, or use `v-show` on the button instead of `v-if`.

The reason that the button doesn't appear is that the button is in a `slot` of the tooltip. Using `v-if`, the button is not rendered, so the slot is blank, forcing the tooltip component to use the default slot contents. You can't re-fill an empty slot, at least in Vuetify. `v-show` works because the button is still rendered to the DOM, it is only hidden.

**USING V-IF ON THE TOOLTIP:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      val: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-container fluid class="text-center">
        <v-row
          class="flex"
          justify="space-between"
        >
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-btn @click="val++">+</v-btn>
            <v-btn @click="val--">-</v-btn>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12">
            {{ val }}
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" class="mt-2">
            <v-tooltip bottom v-if="val > 2">
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn color="green" v-on="on">
                  > 2
                </v-btn>
              </template>
              <span>tooltip</span>
            </v-tooltip>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" class="mt-12">
            <v-btn color="blue" v-if="val > 2">
              > 2
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**USING V-SHOW ON THE BUTTON:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      val: 5
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-container fluid class="text-center">
        <v-row
          class="flex"
          justify="space-between"
        >
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-btn @click="val++">+</v-btn>
            <v-btn @click="val--">-</v-btn>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12">
            {{ val }}
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" class="mt-2">
            <v-tooltip bottom>
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn color="green" v-show="val > 2" v-on="on">
                  > 2
                </v-btn>
              </template>
              <span>tooltip</span>
            </v-tooltip>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" class="mt-12">
            <v-btn color="blue" v-if="val > 2">
              > 2
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```